# Should there be a .py file for each import or from x import statement?

Tags: python, import

I am trying to understand exactly what Python is doing to import statements and install packages. I really want to know the "path" that python follows to accomplish this so I can try and follow along to see how people who have created well known packages have accomplished it.

I created a venv called FlaskVE in a folder. Directory structure (Windows) as follows:

```
c:\users\me\documents\FlaskVE
     \Include
     \Lib
     \Scripts
```

I activated the virtual environment and installed flask using pip

```
$ cd c:\users\me\documents\FlaskVE\Scripts
$ activate
<-current prompt (FlaskVE) c:\users\me\documents\FlaskVE\Scripts
$ pip install flask
$ python
$ from flask import Flask
```

At this point, python looks along my PATH for python packages, since I am in a venv, the PATH points to the current folder I am in. Within \FlaskVE\Lib\site-packages\flask there is not a Flask.py folder. How does Python find the Flask  class? I can see within the **init**.py file within \FlaskVE\Lib\site-packages\flask there is a command "from .app import Flask, Request, Response" and within the app.py file in that directory there is a class called Flask. Is this the one it is importing and if so, does the "from flask" call start the **init**.py file automatically?

Comment: The `flask` **directory** is a package. The presence of the `__init__.py` file makes it a package. You may want to read up first on how those work in the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: And yes, importing a package will load the `__init__.py` file for that package.

Comment: Thank you. So whether it says from or import, the __init__.py file is loaded from that directory?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use `from ... import` or just `import`; the only difference there is what is bound into your current namespace. Both load packages exactly the same way, and yes, when you import `foobar` and `foobar` is a directory with an `__init__.py` file, then that file will be executed to satisfy the import.